# Swift Programatic constraint view.bottomAnchor causing issue

Tags: swift

I am trying to get better at all programatic constraints.

I created an interface representation of what I wanted to do to make sure everything turned blue and gave no errors when ran.

In interface builder I created a UIView, set the ratio to 1:1, top anchor 100, and bottom anchor 450, and horizontally constrained it.

Works great.

Now I deleted all of that and do it via code

I think this should be identical to the IB version...

```
let testView = UIView()

view.addSubview(testView)
        testView.backgroundColor = .red


        let testViewTopConstraint = testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100)
        let testViewBottomConstraint = testView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 450)
        let testViewCenterXConstraint = testView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        let testViewAspectConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: testView,
                                                          attribute: .height,
                                                          relatedBy: .equal,
                                                          toItem: testView,
                                                          attribute: .width,
                                                          multiplier: (1.0 / 1.0),
                                                          constant: 0)


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([testViewTopConstraint, testViewBottomConstraint, testViewCenterXConstraint, testViewAspectConstraint])

        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

When I run it, the red square becomes a rectangle extending to the end (possible beyond).

I have played around with programatic constraints. If I were to add a leading constraint I am perfectly fine, it just seems to be my bottom constraint that always messes me up.

What is wrong with my bottom constraint?
Or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things but to answer your particular issue here you just have to add a - to the 450 constant

```
let testViewBottomConstraint = testView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -450)
```

You can also omit the NSLayoutConstraint by adding a few more anchors.